# What's the status of Android Slices in 2020

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-slices

Most of the question are posted few years back, just curious what's the status so far, I tried to create a simple slice and want to test the connection in prod, but looks like nobody can actually opens the slices component from the Android Search including myself. Just wonder if this feature is officially removed or Google just turn it off from their side?